# What is that big white building?

Tags: plot-explanation, in-time

At the end of **[In Time](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1637688/)** Sylvia and Will are going to rob another building. What is that building and does have some significance on the story?

My guess is a bank, maybe Federal Reserve Building? But I'm not American, so I don't recognize the building.

Comment: Can you include an image of the building? It might help someone who isn't familiar with the film identify it.

Comment: @Longshanks Ok I will try. But I dont have the movie right now. I watch it on TV. Will have to download it.

Comment: Was it this building? http://catrafficticket.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Metropolitan_Courthouse.jpg

Comment: There's a good list of locations, with images, here http://www.seeing-stars.com/Locations/InTime.shtml It might help you find the building you're after.

Comment: @Longshanks yes, the one at the [**end**](http://www.seeing-stars.com/Locations/InTime7.shtml).  Looks like was just something random. Is a Los Angeles City Hall.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### A time bank.

**(In reality it is the Los Angeles City Hall, the west side.)**

[image: Los Angeles City hall]

This is digitally manipulated in the wide shot:

[image: Los Angeles City hall]

And the real-life view:

[232 North Spring Street](https://www.google.com/maps/@34.0540733,-118.2434337,3a,75y,130.08h,90.96t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1s-Gic5eepPU-WWVCPCdlQqg!2e0!6s%2F%2Fgeo0.ggpht.com%2Fcbk%3Fpanoid%3D-Gic5eepPU-WWVCPCdlQqg%26output%3Dthumbnail%26cb_client%3Dmaps_sv.tactile.gps%26thumb%3D2%26w%3D203%26h%3D100%26yaw%3D98.474495%26pitch%3D0%26thumbfov%3D100!7i13312!8i6656)

### Whey are they there? To rob it.

From the summary on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_Time):

> Will and Sylvia continue robbing banks as part of their efforts to crash the system, while the rich attempt to cope with the sudden surge of people infiltrating their zone. In an end scene, they get out of the car whilst reloading their guns, **"Told you there were larger banks"** Sylvia tells a smiling Will, who replies "You almost lost your calling". Exhilarated they both run up the stairs towards the large building, armed and ready to continue the fight... and to live!

Will and Sylvia are giving the time capsules to the needy/poor.